# Turtle NameError

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, nameerror

I started toying  with a program I wrote back in highschool and know I don't remember what the heck I did but now every time i run the below code it gives me a nameerror, and it's been so long since I've toyed with turtle I don't know what I did wrong. You guys helped so much in getting this code to work the first time I though maybe you could help an amateur like me again

I belive it might be the python versions are now different (wrote in 3.5 trying to run in 3.6) but I'm not sure I think i just messed something up somewhere and I'm just not smart enough to figure it out

```
from random import randint
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class MyTurtle(Turtle):

    def petals(self, size=30, count=8, speed=100):
        if size == 30:
            self.begin_fill()

        if size > 0:  # drawing leading edge of petal
            self.fd(3)
            self.rt(3)

            screen.ontimer(lambda: self.petals(size - 1, count, speed), speed)
            return

        if size == 0:  # switch to other edge of petal
            self.rt(90)

        if size > -30:  # drawing trailing edge of petal
            self.fd(3)
            self.rt(3)

            screen.ontimer(lambda: self.petals(size - 1, count, speed), speed)
            return

        self.end_fill()  # finish this petal
        self.lt(230) # prepare for the next petal

        if count > 0:  # drawing the next petal
            screen.ontimer(lambda: self.petals(count=count - 1, speed=speed), speed)
            return

        self.hideturtle()  # finished drawing

    def flowerhead(self):
        self.pencolor('red')   #outlines the flowerpetals in red to see easier
        self.petals(speed=9)   

       # self.petals(speed=randint(50, 250))

def flower1():
    todd.color('green', 'blue')
    todd.goto(0, -270)
    todd.penup()
    todd.showturtle()
    todd.goto(0,0)
    todd.pendown()
    todd.flowerhead()

def flower2():
    tony.color('green', 'purple')
    tony.penup()
    tony.goto(0, -200)
    tony.pendown()
    tony.showturtle()
    tony.goto(80, -15)
    tony.seth(0)
    tony.flowerhead()

def flower3():
    tina.color('green', 'turquoise')
    tina.penup()
    tina.goto(0, -200)
    tina.pendown()
    tina.showturtle()
    tina.goto(-80, -15)
    tina.seth(90)
    tina.flowerhead()

def flower4():
    tiny.color('green', 'black')
    tiny.penup()
    tiny.goto(0, -200)
    tiny.pendown()
    tiny.showturtle()
    tiny.goto(160, -25)
    tiny.seth(90)
    tiny.flowerhead()


def flower5():
    tweeny.color('green', 'pink')
    tweeny.penup()
    tweeny.goto(0, -200)
    tweeny.pendown()
    tweeny.showturtle()
    tweeny.goto(-160, -25)
    tweeny.seth(90)
    tweeny.flowerhead()

def writing():
    teacher.penup()
    teacher.setpos(0, 120)
    teacher.pendown()
    teacher.color('red')
    teacher.write('test', align='center', font=('Times New Roman', 30, 'normal'))

tony = MyTurtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
todd = MyTurtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
tina = MyTurtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
tiny = MyTurtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
tweeny = MyTurtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)
teacher = MyTurtle(shape='turtle', visible=False)

screen = getScreen()
screen.title('I am epic')
screen.delay(0)

screen.ontimer(flower2, 6500)
screen.ontimer(flower4, 0)
screen.ontimer(flower3, 6500)
screen.ontimer(flower5, 0)
screen.ontimer(flower1, 13000)

screen.ontimer(writing, 26000)

screen.mainloop()
```

the line that gives me the error is

```
screen = getScreen()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\programming\trig class\Multiple flowers runnig at once.py", line 106, in <module>
    screen = getscreen()
NameError: name 'getscreen' is not defined
```

Like I said, i think it's the versions but I'd appreciate a second, third or even fourth opinion I'm just  a student trying to learn how to not be stupid

Comment: where did you define `getscreen()`? the error is pretty clear, did you mean `turtle.getscreen()`?

Comment: I don't know i wrote this in 12th grade, I don't know where i should define it, I don't even know why I tried it that way, I'm actually pretty close to just rewriting the entire thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined scree as get screen like this:

```
screen=getScreen()
```

this is an old version of calling the screen 
try using the new version which is

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
```

Comment: this did work but I had to delete the turtle. part and just leave 'screen = Screen()'